# how to count row group in select mysql?

Tags: mysql

hj all, help me!!
    I use MYSQL, i have a table with data:

```
   |id  |  str |
  -------------
   1      aabb
   2      aaac
   3      aaad
   4      aabb
   5      aabb
   6      aaac
```

i want a query mysql (or function) select return result:

```
       STT  | str |
       1     aabb
       1     aaac
       1     aaad
       2     aabb
       3     aabb
       2     aaac
```

STT is number str appears in table
thanks!

Comment: what you want exactly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try this

```
SELECT A.id, A.str, count(*) AS STT
FROM Table1 A
JOIN Table1 B ON A.str = B.str AND A.id >= B.id
GROUP BY A.id, A.str
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2d8c0/2)**

**Output:**

```
ID  STR STT
1   aabb    1
2   aaac    1
3   aaad    1
4   aabb    2
5   aabb    3
6   aaac    2
```